# why i can edit my first object with my handmade jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins

my jQuery plugin is simple but it only works in my first object

I tried to solve it with a for loop but i can't do that

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.omToolTip = function (userOptions) {
        var options = $.extend({
            width: 200,
        }, userOptions)

        this.each(function () {
            var elm = $(this);
            var ttBox = $("<div>").attr("class", "ttb");

            elm.hover(function () {
                alert("salam");
            }, function () {
                alert("khodafez");
            })

        })
    }
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: How are you using this plugin?

Comment: Let me guess .. you're using this plugin with `id` change it to class and try again .. id should be unique so don't use same id for more than one element

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef  is a solution to use this plugin for elements with same id???

Comment: @Taplar in a html file with <script> tag

Comment: @Omidgh see my answer

Comment: @Omidgh and about Tapler question he asked how you use not how you include .. *in a html file with `<script>` tag* is the answer of how you include ..

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef that doesn't tell me how the user is actually using it.  `$(selector).omToolTip(...)` is what I'm asking about.

Comment: Yes, That's what I meant @Taplar .. cause of that I commented in code in my answer `// How to use?` before the line you're talking about ;) ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Let me guess .. you're using this plugin with id change it to class
>   and try again .. id should be unique so don't use same id for more
>   than one element

No you shouldn't duplicate id .. Take a look at the next example to know the difference between using same class and same id

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // How to use?
  $('.anyDiv').omToolTip(); // elements with same class
  $('#anyDiv').omToolTip(); // elements with same id just the first one will work if you use id
});
(function ($) {
    $.fn.omToolTip = function (userOptions) {
        var options = $.extend({
            width: 200,
        }, userOptions)

        this.each(function () {
            var elm = $(this);
            var ttBox = $("<div>").addClass("ttb"); // use addClass instead of attr

            elm.hover(function () {
                console.log("salam");
            }, function () {
                console.log("khodafez");
            })

        })
    }
})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- With same Class -->
<div class="anyDiv">Class Any Div</div>
<div class="anyDiv">Class Any Div</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>


<!-- With same Id (only the first one here will work with the plugin)-->
<div id="anyDiv">Id Any Div</div>
<div id="anyDiv">Id Any Div</div>
```

Also to add class you can use `.addClass()` instead of `attr('class'.....)`

Comment: You're totally welcome @Omidgh .. Have a nice day :-)